# Is it possible to start a browser and run process in the background in robotframework?

Tags: automation, robotframework

I need to run a process from a powershell script, which I am adding to the Suite setup for my robot tests. Now after the Start/run process has been completed I need to open the browser to run my tests. When I try to do that the powershell starts the process but waits indefinitely, and does not opens the browser at all. Why? There is nothing in the log to clarify the reason. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

okay I have found the reason why it was not opening the browser because the application need to start in localhost and local host needs time to start. Therefore adding wait until network is idle with timeouts keyword helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

while executing you code it takes some time for open browser... right!

you can use this keyword:

```
 Sleep   |   10s     (based on time taken for open browser you can increase or decrease time here)
```

Or else, use this command

```
  Wait Until Element Is Visible  id=" "  timeout=10
```

After that next test cases will run automatically.

Regards

Abhishek K